# Cannot reverse tunnel between my local machine and my open solaris server

Tags: ssh-tunnel, sunos, joyent

I want to reverse tunnel connection to my SunOS (Joyent) so that any connections coming to 12043 on this server will be served by my local development server running at localhost:8843.

**Edit**: I don't know why but SO is not formatting my post properly (damn). Any experienced guy please help edit my post

So here what I do:

1. Start my local server at port 8843

   `$ telnet localhost 8843

   Trying 127.0.0.1...

   Connected to localhost.

   Escape character is '^]'.`
2. Connect to server

   `$ ssh -vgR *:12043:0.0.0.0:8843 jill@myhost.com

   OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
   debug1: Reading configuration data /x/x/.ssh/config
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
   debug1: Connecting to myhost.com [x.x.x.x] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file /x/x/.ssh/identity type -1
   debug1: identity file /x/x/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
   debug1: identity file /x/x/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_1.4
   debug1: no match: Sun_SSH_1.4
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
   debug1: Host 'eastagile.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
   debug1: Found key in /x/x/.ssh/known_hosts:65
   debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Offering public key: eastagile5
   debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
   debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
   debug1: Remote connections from *:12043 forwarded to local address 0.0.0.0:8843
   debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
   debug1: Entering interactive session.
   debug1: remote forward success for: listen 12043, connect 0.0.0.0:8843
   debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
   Last login: Wed Mar 30 09:47:43 2011 from y.y.y`
3. Then do a check

   `$ telnet myhost.com 12043

   Trying x.x.x.x...

   telnet: connect to address x.x.x.x: Connection refused

   telnet: Unable to connect to remote host`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing 0.0.0.0 with the IP you actually want the connection to be forwarded *to*. E.g.:

```
ssh -vgR *:12043:localhost:8843 jill@myhost.com
```

Comment: Shouldn't your localhost be the name of the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your servers sshd_config?

I have not worked with solaris myself in some time however you must have

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

For this to work, in RHEL and derived distros (CentOS etc...)